# How to stop scrolling of a div when it reaches on a specific div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

After clicking on a button im getting a pop up. What i want to achieve is to stop scrolling of this pop up when it reaches to the menu of my website.

here is my code

```
<div id="dialog_box" class="dbox" style="display: none; position: fixed;                
right: 192px ! important; z-index: 1000; top: 0px;">
```

I want to stop scrolling of #dialog_box when it reaches to #menu id div using jquery or java script.

I have tried this so far but its not working

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
jQuery('#dialog_box').scrollTo('#menu'); // i would like to stop scrolling of dialog_box when it meet the #menu id div.
jQuery("#dialog_box").css("top", Math.max(0, 162 -    
jQuery(this).scrollTop()));  // i have tried this to position dialog_box from top but its not giving me the exact result.
});
});
```

Comment: Definitely, a concrete online sample would help to understand your expected behaviour, i guess

Comment: i want to stop scrolling of #dialog_box till matched target element(#menu)

Comment: please check this link http://www.soukai.my/ and click on add to cart button then scroll to top i want to stop scrolling when it reaches to the website menu

Comment: So posted answer should help you to get expected behaviour

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a detailed tutorial on this.

I am sure this will help.

http://css-tricks.com/scroll-fix-content/

Answer (score 2):

you can use the js code like this

```
  var wrap = $("#wrap");    
  wrap.on("scroll", function(e) {  
    if (this.scrollTop > 100) {
       wrap.addClass("class_name_of_div");
    } else {
       wrap.removeClass("class_name_of_div");
    }
});
```

and in .CSS

```
.class_name_of_div{
    position: fixed;
        top: 10px;
}
```

try this will work